# how to set object's position according to background picture's position on HTML5?

Tags: css, html, html5-canvas

i have a project on HTML5. In background image is football field. And football player's names (label or button) are its over. how to set these object's positions (pixel or what else) according to background image's position?

the best way is using table?

Answer (score 3):

You can use **position** CSS property (http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp, http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/). All you have to do is to set relative position for container with the background and absolute position with proper offset for elements which are over it.

And no, table is not the best way. Use **section** or just **div** instead.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at background positioning. It will work on HTML5 Canvas's.

```
background-position: right-pixels-or-percentage top-pixels-or-percentage;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp